# Populating Android Spinner with LivaData from Firebase

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner, android-viewmodel

How do I load a spinner with data I have saved in Firebase RTDB?

I was thinking something like this  might work

```
    viewModel.liveCharacterModel.observe(this, Observer { spinnerData ->
            val spinnerAdapter =  ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerData)
            select_character.adapter = spinnerAdapter
        })
```

but I am getting an error on ArrayAdapter
"None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied."

this is my characterViewModel code if that's relevant

```
class CharacterViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val dbCharacterModels = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(NODE_CHARACTERS)

    //add data from db to this list for use in the
    // characterModelAdapter class for the recycler view
    private val _characters = MutableLiveData<List<CharacterModel>>()
    val characterModel: LiveData<List<CharacterModel>>
        get() = _characters

    //live data for new data added
    private val _liveCharacters = MutableLiveData<CharacterModel>()
    val liveCharacterModel: LiveData<CharacterModel>
        get() = _liveCharacters

    private val _result = MutableLiveData<Exception?>()
    val result: LiveData<Exception?>
        get() = _result

    private val childEventListener = object : ChildEventListener {

        override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
            val liveCharacterModel = snapshot.getValue(CharacterModel::class.java)
            liveCharacterModel?.id = snapshot.key
            _liveCharacters.value = liveCharacterModel
        }

        override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
            val liveCharacterModel = snapshot.getValue(CharacterModel::class.java)
            liveCharacterModel?.id = snapshot.key
            _liveCharacters.value = liveCharacterModel
        }

        override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val liveCharacterModel = snapshot.getValue(CharacterModel::class.java)
            liveCharacterModel?.id = snapshot.key
            liveCharacterModel?.charDeleted = true
            _liveCharacters.value = liveCharacterModel
        }

        override fun onChildMoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    }

    /*
        Add character to DB, save a character under the characters node in the DB with a
        unique key id.

     */
    fun addCharacter(character: CharacterModel) {

        character.id = dbCharacterModels.push().key
        character.id?.let {
            dbCharacterModels.child(it).setValue(character).addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    _result.value = null
                } else {
                    _result.value = it.exception
                }
            }
        }

    }

    fun getDBUpdates() {
        dbCharacterModels.addChildEventListener(childEventListener)
    }

    /*
     Fetch data from the db, make sure the data is not null, add it to a list and assign
     it to the mutable list which gets displayed in the fragment
     */
    fun getCharacters() {
        dbCharacterModels.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    val characters = mutableListOf<CharacterModel>()
                    for (characterSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val character = characterSnapshot.getValue(CharacterModel::class.java)
                        character?.id = characterSnapshot.key
                        character?.let { characters.add(it) }
                    }
                    _characters.value = characters
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })
    }

    //overrite existing character with new values
    fun editCharacter(character: CharacterModel) {
        dbCharacterModels.child(character.id!!).setValue(character)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    _result.value = null
                } else {
                    _result.value = it.exception
                }
            }
    }

    fun deleteCharacter(character: CharacterModel) {
        dbCharacterModels.child(character.id!!).setValue(null)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    _result.value = null
                } else {
                    _result.value = it.exception
                }
            }
    }

    //remove the event listener when fragment is destroyed
    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        dbCharacterModels.removeEventListener(childEventListener)
    }
}
```

This is my CharacterModelAdapter code which I use for displying data in a recycler view incase its relevent also

```
class CharacterModelAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<CharacterModelAdapter.CharacterViewModel>() {

    private var characters = mutableListOf<CharacterModel>()
     var listener: CharacterRecyclerViewListener? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = CharacterViewModel (
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_character, parent,  false))


    override fun getItemCount() = characters.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CharacterModelAdapter.CharacterViewModel, position: Int) {
        holder.view.text_view_name.text = characters[position].name
        holder.view.text_view_race.text = characters[position].race
        holder.view.text_view_class.text = characters[position].classType

        holder.view.edit_character.setOnClickListener {
            listener?.onRecyclerViewButtonClick(it, characters[position]) 
        }
        holder.view.delete_character.setOnClickListener {
            listener?.onRecyclerViewButtonClick(it, characters[position])
        }
    }

    fun setCharcaters(characters: List<CharacterModel>) {
        this.characters = characters as MutableList<CharacterModel>
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    /*
    function that checks if a character is already in the list before adding
    checks if charDeleted is true or false for deleting and also checks which index the character
    is at for editing. notifyDatasetChaged is then called so the recycler view updates and displays
    the changes

     */
    fun addCharacter(character: CharacterModel) {
        if(!characters.contains(character)) {
            characters.add(character)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        } else {
            val index = characters.indexOf(character)
            if(character.charDeleted) {
                characters.removeAt(index)
            }else {
                characters[index] = character
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class CharacterViewModel(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
}
```

This is the popup fragment I want to implement the spinner inside

```
class CreateRaidPopupFragment: DialogFragment(), AnkoLogger {
    private lateinit var viewModel: CharacterViewModel
    private val adapter = CharacterModelAdapter()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_raid_popup, container, false)
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.liveCharacterModel.observe(this, Observer { spinnerData ->
            val spinnerAdapter =  ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerData)
            select_character.adapter = spinnerAdapter
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed it, I needed to change my function

```
viewModel.characterModel.observe(this, Observer {
        val spinnerAdapter =
            ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, it)
        select_character.adapter = spinnerAdapter
    })
```

and also I needed to call the getCharacters function before this